# Switching from old CRT monitor to new LED monitor

Tags: display

I have been using a Dell CRT monitor for years. Today, I bought a new Samsung LED monitor, and was under the impression that simply switching the monitors should work.

However, when I disconnected the old one and connected the new one, a message on the monitor says something in the line that it needs 1920X1080, 60 Hz optimal settings. Nothing else is displayed. When I switch back to the old one, I can not find such an entry to select from in the monitor settings.

- My system: Ubuntu 15.04, *updated*
- Old monitor: Dell CRT 16"
- New monitor: Samsung LED 21.5"

Now, what will be the best way for me to move forward? Carry out new installation of Ubuntu with the new monitor connected? Or, is there a short cut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu does not recognize a new monitor when it is replaced on the fly. That is, when the computer is running, and you yank out the cable of the old monitor and put in the new one. **This is not safe, and may damage your computer and / or monitor.**

1. The proper method is to turn the computer off.
2. Turn the old monitor off.
3. Unplug the old monitor from its power source.
4. Plug the new monitor (LCD) to the computer.
5. Plug the new monitor to the power source, and turn it on.
6. Finally, turn the computer on.

**When the computer is turned back on, it will verify that a monitor is connected and at that time it will set itself up for the new monitor.**

[The same method should be used for other operating systems.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-replace-your-computer-monitor.html).

Rebooting the computer with the new monitor connected works too.

Hope this helps

Comment: Interestingly (but dangerously), the sales clerk checked my monitor by yanking the cable out of another one and the plugging it into mine.

Comment: That is interesting indeed. May be it works with the newer digital standards like HDMI and DisplayPort. May be it works with Windows. May be the sales person does not care, as he would mark the monitor as defective if it shorts out because of his stupidity. In the days of CRTs and VGA cables this was never a good idea. Welcome to the flat screen LED world.